# wkhtmltopdf fails with --footer-center argument

Tags: wkhtmltopdf

Im trying to insert text into the footer with wkhtmltopdf.

```
wkhtmltopdf ../input.html ../output.pdf --footer-center="My Text"
```

But it just gives me the error

```
Unknown long argument --footer-center=My Text
```

I have tried many ways

```
wkhtmltopdf ../input.html ../output.pdf --footer-center=My Text
wkhtmltopdf --footer-center="My Text" ../input.html ../output.pdf
wkhtmltopdf ../input.html --footer-center="My Text" ../output.pdf
```

But all results in

```
Unknown long argument --footer-center=My Text
```

Im using `wkhtmltopdf 0.12.1 (with patched qt)`

And `man wkhtmltopdf` describes the `--footer-center` argument

And of course input.html already exists in the parent directory, and everything works perfect if I dont add the --footer-center argument

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Instead of `=` the parameter value has to be separated by  (a space).

```
wkhtmltopdf --footer-center "My Text" ../input.html ../output.pdf
```

And with multiple

```
wkhtmltopdf --footer-center "My Text" --footer-left "Left content" ../input.html ../output.pdf
```