# wkhtmltopdf fails, when using --footer arg if executed programmatically

Tags: java, footer, wkhtmltopdf

This question is similiar to [wkhtmltopdf fails with --footer-center argument](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/28746794/wkhtmltopdf-fails-with-footer-center-argument).
But the way of running wkhtmltopdf is different.

Im using:

```
wkhtmltopdf 0.12.2.2 (with patched qt)
```

on Windows 7 / 64 Bit

When I use the following command in console:

```
wkhtmltopdf --print-media-type --footer-center [page] "test.html" "test.pdf"
```

everything runs like expected. 
But when I do the same programmatically from Java, like:

```
 List<String> command = new ArrayList<String>();
 command.add("wkhtmltopdf.exe");
 command.add("--footer-center [page]");   
 command.add("--print-media-type");
 command.add(htmlFilename);
 command.add(pdfFilename);
 ProcessBuilder builder = new ProcessBuilder(command);
 ...
```

the pdf gets not created. When I omit the line (commenting out)

```
command.add("--footer-center [page]");
```

everything runs as expected.. so the problem deals with that argument for wkhtmltopdf..

Does anyone know how to resolve this issue ?